# check box issue during editing in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp

This is advertisement query

```
INSERT into advertise_management(advertisement_name,adv_code) values('".$adv_name."','".$adv_code."')
```

post management:

```
<input type="text" name="post_name" value="<?php if(isset($post_value)){ echo $post_value['post_name'];} else { echo ''; }?>" required="required">
<?php  $res=  mysql_query("select * from advertise_management ");
while($result= mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $adv=$result['advertisement_name'];
{ ?>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $adv?>" name="post_adv[]">
<?php } ?>
```

Post Management insert query :

```
$post_name = $_POST['post_name'];  
$post_adv1 = $_POST['post_adv'];
$post_adv = implode(",", $post_adv1);
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$res = mysql_query("INSERT into post_managment(post_name,post_adv) values('".$post_name."','".$post_adv."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Post management edit :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   post_managment where post_id='$pid'");

$post_value = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
><input type="text" name="post_name" value="<?php if(isset($post_value)){ echo $post_value['post_name'];} else { echo ''; }?>" required="required">

<?php  $res=  mysql_query("select * from advertise_management ");
while($result= mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $adv=$result['advertisement_name'];
{ ?>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $adv?>" name="post_adv[]">
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" value="" id="create"><input type="reset" value="" id="cancel">
```

I want to return the values that is checked and the values that is not checked.

Answer (score 2):

The browser normally won't send anything for checkboxes that aren't checked. You can work around this by also rendering a hidden input () with the same name and a different value. Make sure it's output right before the checkbox.

Comment: ya .. value is storing.I want to display which is checked which is unchecked thats all. I dont know how to display which is checked one which is unchecked.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the "checked" attribute. http://help.dottoro.com/lhpiwrem.php